# How do I specify multiple targets and projects in my podfile for my Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have one workspace that contains 3 projects (Project1, Project2), which Project1 contains 2 targets (Target1, Target2), and Project2 contains 1 target (target3).
And the directory structure looks like the diagram below.

How do I setup Podfile so every target has the pod 'RestKit'?

I don't know what 'link_with' and 
Please write me the podfile and explain to me, thank you a lot.

```
    MyApp
|
+-- MyApp.xcworkspace
|
+-- Project1
|    |
|    +-- Target1.xcodeproj
|    +-- (source code)
|    |
|    +-- Target2
|    +-- (source code)
|
|
+-- Project2
|    |
|    +-- Target3.xcodeproj
|    +-- (source code)
|
+-- Target3
     |
     +-- (source code)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This Podfile hasn't been verified, but may show you a basic idea of multiple projects and targets setting.

```
workspace 'MyApp'
xcodeproj 'Project1/Project1.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'Project2/Project2.xcodeproj'

target :Target1 do
    platform :ios, '6.0'
    pod 'RestKit'
    xcodeproj 'Project1/Project1.xcodeproj'
end

target :Target2 do
    platform :ios, '6.0'
    pod 'RestKit'
    xcodeproj 'Project2/Project2.xcodeproj'
end

target :Target3 do
    platform :ios, '6.0'
    pod 'RestKit'
    xcodeproj 'Project1/Project1.xcodeproj'
end
```

The first line specifies your workspace. Check http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#workspace

Second line and third line specify your xcodeprojs.
http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#xcodeproj

And then, specify pod dependencies for targets one by one.

Comment: I have verified it. It works, with little modifying: 
"target :ALplayCocoapod do" instead of "target : ALplayCocoapod do", no space needed.

Also, my example of the directory structure was wrong. There's only one xcodeproj for one project, which may contains multiple targets.

Thnkas a lot, your explanation is even better than official one.

Comment: For me what fixed it was the `xcodeproj` line within the `target do ... end` section.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working example from https://github.com/dblock/ARASCIISwizzle:

```
workspace 'ARASCIISwizzle'

pod 'ARASCIISwizzle', :path => 'ARASCIISwizzle.podspec'

xcodeproj 'Demo.xcodeproj'

target 'Demo' do
  pod 'FLKAutoLayout', '~> 0.1.1'
  xcodeproj 'Demo.xcodeproj'
end

target 'IntegrationTests' do
  pod 'Specta', '~> 0.2.1'
  pod 'Expecta', '~> 0.2.3'
  pod 'FBSnapshotTestCase', :head
  pod 'EXPMatchers+FBSnapshotTest', :head
  xcodeproj 'Demo.xcodeproj'
end

target 'Tests' do
  pod 'Specta', '~> 0.2.1'
  pod 'Expecta', '~> 0.2.3'
  pod 'FBSnapshotTestCase', :head
  pod 'EXPMatchers+FBSnapshotTest', :head
  pod 'OCMock', '~> 2.2.3'
  xcodeproj 'Tests.xcodeproj'
end
```

Note the discussion in https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1922, the CocoaPods team is reworking this DSL to be less backwards.

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of CocoaPods `xcodeproj` is substituted with `project`.

Given the project structure:

```
MyApp
├- MyApp.xcworkspace
├- Project1
   ├- Target1.xcodeproj
   ├- Target2.xcodeproj
├- Project2
   ├- Target3.xcodeproj
```

`Podfile` will look like this:

```
workspace 'MyApp'

project 'Project1/Target1.xcodeproj'
project 'Project1/Target2.xcodeproj'

project 'Project2/Target3.xcodeproj'


target 'Target1' do
    project 'Project1/Target1.xcodeproj'
    pod 'RestKit'
end

target 'Target2' do
    project 'Project1/Target2.xcodeproj'
    pod 'RestKit'
end

target 'Target3' do
    project 'Project2/Target3.xcodeproj'
    pod 'RestKit'
end
```